# Critical and regular values of a map from $T^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $T^2$ be the torus in $\mathbb{R^3}$, $\pi:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ be the projection $\pi(x,y,z)=(y,z)$ and $p:T^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ the restriction of $p$ to $T^2$. I need help finding the critical and regular values of the map $p$. Any assistance is appreciated!

Definitions: If a differential of a map fails to be surjective at a point then it is a critical point. If a point is in the image of a critical point then it is a critical value. If not, it is a regular value.

Comment: @ALB Honestly I don't know how to get started

Comment: @ALB Do I need to write down the equation of the torus first?

Comment: I would write down the equation for the torus first. Especially since we are considering $T^{2}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, this problem can be a simplified to a question of multivariable calculus.

Comment: I would also write down the definitions of "critical" and "regular" points, to remind myself of exactly what they mean in this context.

Comment: @ALB check the edit

Comment: I'd recommend writing down a parameterized representation of the torus (i.e., a map from $[0, 2\pi] \times [0, 2\pi] \to \Bbb R^3$ whose image is the torus. Also: make sure that the torus is "lying" on the $xz$-plane or the $xy$-plane, rather than on the $yz$-plane. Otherwise your critical points won't be distinct. (Your problem doesn't require this, but it'll be the wise choice, I promise.)

Comment: I wrote my hint exactly wrong: you want the "plane" of the torus to be the $yz$ plane. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

It may be instructive to first solve the simpler problem: What are the critical values of the projection map onto $\mathbb{R}$? This is a common introductory problem in Morse theory, as this is easily visualized as the "height" map. Usually the torus is hung vertically to make the map interesting.

The critical values here are precisely those points which correspond to saddles, basins, or peaks in the torus' geometry. You could, of course, prove this by writing down an actual parameterization, and then the problem would become a question of computing the Jacobian and checking the necessary conditions. But ideally you could use certain theorems to help you out. For example, you might have access to the [preimage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem), which would tell you something about the preimages of your regular values. From there, you could use your geometric intuition about which parts of the projection have such preimages. This would give you a picture of all the regular values, and their complement would be your critical values. Since you've tagged it as "differential topology", and not "advanced calculus", hopefully you have elegant tools such as this, and you don't need to get your hands so dirty.